# Module pattern: Binding/unbinding prototype method to $(window)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am writing a plugin (called `test`) using the module pattern (Query boilerplate; https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js.).

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hgTz/

---

We have two `div`s. For each `div`:

1. `x()` is fired on `$(window)` scroll.
2. `destroy()` is fired on clicking the `div`. This unbinds the `scroll` method.

---

```
Plugin.prototype = {

  bind: function() {
    this.element.addClass( 'active' );
    $( window ).on( 'scroll.' + pluginName, $.proxy( this.x, this ) );
    this.element.on( 'click.' + pluginName, $.proxy( this.destroy, this ) );
  },

  destroy: function() {
    this.element.removeClass( 'active' );
    $( window ).off( 'scroll.' + pluginName, $.proxy( this.x, this ) );
    // unbinds scroll for all instances!
  },

  x: function() {
    console.log( 'x' );
  }

}
```

**Problem:** The `destroy()` method unbinds `x()` from all instances, as opposed to *just for the particular instance that was clicked*.

Am I using `jQuery.proxy()` incorrectly? How do I correctly bind and unbind a method in `plugin.prototype` to/from `$(window)`?

Comment: $.proxy generates a new function each time you use it. Using it with .off() isn't going to work as expected since .off needs the original function, not an identical one.

Comment: you are binding handler to all elements, you cannot remove this handler to only one specific element inside matched set. Could be a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/3hgTz/1/